# I am not getting the result properly when conneting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

For the code below added, i am not getting any result printed.

```
$con = @mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","temp");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query="SELECT * FROM `login`";
echo $query;
$result=@mysqli_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row["username"];
}
```

Comment: Don't mix mysql and mysqli functions. And remove @ ....

Comment: If i remove @, am getting warning messages

Comment: warning messages are there to help you

Comment: For a programmer it is ok. But a user get irritated while seeing these warning messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code it will work

```
 //conection: 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","temp") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con)); 

//consultation: 

$query = "SELECT * FROM login" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($con)); 

//execute the query. 

$result = $con->query($query); 

//display information: 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  echo $row["username"] . "<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: $con->query() is looking like calling function. how is it working?

Comment: have your try the above code? it will execute the $query variable query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","temp");
// Here localhost is host name, root is username, password is empty and temp is database name.
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  echo $row["username"] . "<br>"; 
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Use this. it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code as it is.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","temp");
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login");
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
              echo $row["username"];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// use this code  and plz check your db name
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$db_name='temp';
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);
if($con)
{
echo "db connect succecssfully";
}

$slt="select * from login";
$query=mysqli_query($slt,$con);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $row["username"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//connection 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```